# What does "its own video driver" mean in RDP's definition

Tags: graphics-card, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, remotefx

Another question from superuser.com gave an definition of RDP, also an definition of RDP from MSDN
[Remote desktop graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/690611/remote-desktop-graphics-card/690613#690613?newreg=0a31caf0ac6a4a6381c8d65721568fcc)

It mentioned that

> On the server, RDP uses its own video driver to render display output
>   by constructing the rendering information into network packets by
>   using RDP protocol and sending them over the network to the client. On
>   the client, RDP receives rendering data and interprets the packets
>   into corresponding Microsoft Windows graphics device interface (GDI)
>   API calls.

I don't understand here about "its own video driver". If i connect to a Windows Server 2012 R2, RDP will use always software video driver? or it will choose the best video driver installed on the server (like a graphic card's video driver)?

How does RemoteFx helps RDP? Is RemoteFx helps improving "its own video driver"?

How does GPU helps RemoteFX hardware compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP uses its own video driver. RemoteFX is a set of features - GPU virtualization, adaptive encoding and smart WAN protocol - all of which help improve RDP.  Following blog posts provide an overview of these features.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/06/06/understanding-and-evaluating-remotefx-vgpu-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/08/06/remotefx-adaptive-graphics-in-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8.aspx